# Does it make a difference which sector you visit?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

When traveling to the next sector in FTL, does your choice make much of a difference?  It seems that you fight slightly different ships, but the difficulty and equipment you find doesn't seem to very.  And, of course, Nebulas seem more Nebulous.

Are green sectors less dangerous than red?  Are there certain encounters that are more common in an Engi sector over a Rock sector?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Different areas feature different events, encounters and nodes.

- Nebulas will have approx 3+ nodes that are NOT sensor-disrupting nebulas.
- Homeworlds feature specific events that allow you to unlock some ships.
- Pirate sector got plenty of pirates (totally unpredictable)
- Race-controlled sectors will mostly have that race pilots (good luck boarding a Mantis crew of 5)

Although it's randomized, it doesn't take a load of thought to know what you'll find. Zoltan sector = loads of Zoltan = easy to teleport in and slay em. Rock sector = loads of stoners = teleport in, kite them around the ship, breaking their systems (they're too slow to *ketchup*)

TL;DR: Yes, there is a differense between regions, and red regions have more hostile encounters than green ones.

Comment: Different kinds of regions generate with different possible numbers of shops, floating items, empty spaces, distress beacons, quests, neutral encounters, hostile encounters, and nebula spaces. In addition to this, some quests will have access to unique quests, events, and encounters. See: http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Sectors

Comment: So... what you are trying to say is... "Regions tend to be different"?

Comment: In the Advanced Edition, Zoltan sectors have one particularly nasty danger - if your crew is fighting multiple Zoltans who have boarded your ship in the same room, they can easily succumb to a lethal chain reaction of Zoltan death throes.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Sectors vary significantly in events.

The weight of different events can change (e.g. pirate zones contain almost exclusively pirate events) and some events are zone-specific (e.g. the Mantis stasis pod occurs only in Mantis zones).